# how to use Network Flow to solve this?

Tags: algorithm, network-flow

suppose we have a binary matrix (only zero or one elements).Adjacent elements of a given element is all 4 elements above,below,on the left and on the right of that element(if they exist). inversion is a pair which its numbers are different and also are adjacent.cost of a matrix is b*q where b is a natural number and q is number of inversions. we can flip any element by cost of a. so we want to minimize x*a + q*b where x is the number of flipped elements.

I think I can consider all elements as nodes and a source which is connected to all zero elements and a sink which is connected to all one elements. But I can find a good way to define edges between nodes and define their capacity till the answer of Network Flow problem be the answer of the original problem

Comment: I don't understand the problem. When does an element of a matrix not exist, do you mean the entry at (0,0) only has the neighbors (0,1) and (1,0) because (-1,0) and (0,-1) don't exist?

Comment: yes exactly..elements at the first or the last forth rows and columns don't have 16 neighbours

Comment: i think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270876/finding-minimum-cost-in-a-binary-matrix?lq=1 is a related question

Comment: David closed your question because a question like it was already asked; find the link at the top, it will take you to a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using Mathematica documentation (you can use pseudo code if you want):

To find maximum flow in a graph

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximumFlow.html

To minimize x*a+q*b

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming.html
- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimum.html
- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html

To define edges between nodes and define their capacity

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyMatrix.html
- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyGraph.html

Comment: It doesn't sound to me like amir has difficulties finding an implementation of flow networks he can use; it rather sounds to me like he has difficulties modeling his problem as a maxflow problem.

Comment: @Margus as bach said i want to model my problem by network flow not just solving any maximum network flow problem or other mentioned problems in these links